# Let B be the family of all intervals of the form [a,b).

Tags: general-topology, generalized-topology

Then B is the basis for a half-open topology denoted by T" in R.

Show that (R,T") is first countable but not second countable.

How can I prove it ?

Comment: Have you managed to prove it is first countable? Or have you managed to prove it is not second countable?

Comment: [Related, but different question:](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971358/proving-a-b-is-first-countable-but-not-second-countable).  OP reasked as requested with different question phrasing.

Comment: It's called the Sorgenfrey line.It also has another proper name.

Answer (score 1):

1. For real $r$ consider $\{[r,r+q): r<q\in \mathbb Q\}.$
2. If $C$ is any base for $T''$ then for each real $r$ there exists $f(r)\in C$ such that $r\in f(r)\subset [r,r+1).$ Consider $\{f(r): r\in \mathbb R\}.$